# Get the drive letter of USB drive in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, usb, wmi

I've seen articles in C# and some other languages that explain how to achieve what I'm looking for but I don't know how to convert them.

- The following link explains how to get the answer:
  [How can I get the drive letter of an USB device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6653205/how-can-i-get-the-drive-letter-of-an-usb-device)
  Win32_DiskDrive-> Win32_DiskDriveToDiskPartition -> Win32_DiskPartition -> Win32_LogicalDiskToPartition -> Win32_LogicalDisk
- The answer by GEOCHET explains also explains how to achieve the answer but again, not in PowerShell: [How to find USB drive letter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123927/how-to-find-usb-drive-letter)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try:

```
gwmi win32_diskdrive | ?{$_.interfacetype -eq "USB"} | %{gwmi -Query "ASSOCIATORS OF {Win32_DiskDrive.DeviceID=`"$($_.DeviceID.replace('\','\\'))`"} WHERE AssocClass = Win32_DiskDriveToDiskPartition"} |  %{gwmi -Query "ASSOCIATORS OF {Win32_DiskPartition.DeviceID=`"$($_.DeviceID)`"} WHERE AssocClass = Win32_LogicalDiskToPartition"} | %{$_.deviceid}
```

Tested with one and more than one USB device plugged-in.

Comment: Thanks, just incase anyone wants the non-alias version:    Get-WmiObject Win32_diskdrive | Where-Object {$_.interfacetype -eq "USB"} |
ForEach-Object {Get-WmiObject -Query "ASSOCIATORS OF {Win32_DiskDrive.DeviceID=`"$($_.DeviceID.replace('\','\\'))`"} WHERE AssocClass = Win32_DiskDriveToDiskPartition"} |
ForEach-Object {Get-WmiObject -Query "ASSOCIATORS OF {Win32_DiskPartition.DeviceID=`"$($_.DeviceID)`"} WHERE AssocClass = Win32_LogicalDiskToPartition"} |
ForEach-Object {$_.deviceid}

Comment: Thanks for the time in writing the answer :-)

Comment: If the shell you're running in is `cmd.exe`, as it is in some shell execution subroutines of older languages, you need to escape the quotes and run like so: `powershell -noprofile "gwmi win32_diskdrive | ?{$_.interfacetype -eq \"USB\"} | %{gwmi -Query \"ASSOCIATORS OF {Win32_DiskDrive.DeviceID=`\"$($_.DeviceID.replace('\','\\'))`\"} WHERE AssocClass = Win32_DiskDriveToDiskPartition\"} |  %{gwmi -Query \"ASSOCIATORS OF {Win32_DiskPartition.DeviceID=`\"$($_.DeviceID)`\"} WHERE AssocClass = Win32_LogicalDiskToPartition\"} | %{$_.deviceid}"`

Answer (score 7):

I know the subject has been dropped for a while, but since it's something I come back to pretty often, I thought I'd update things a bit.

If using Windows 7 and above, a much simpler solution would be:

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_Volume -Filter "DriveType='2'"
```

And if you want to avoid magic numbers:

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_Volume -Filter ("DriveType={0}" -f [int][System.IO.DriveType]::Removable)
```

References:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/vdswmi/win32-volume
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.drivetype

Comment: Note that Windows does not necessarily mount all USB volumes as DriveType 2 (Removable Disk) in Win32_Volume.  USB hard drives that get mounted with disk write caching enabled will mount as DriveType 3 (Local Disk) which is what any standard controller attached volume will show up as.

Answer (score 5):

```
get-volume | where drivetype -eq removable | foreach driveletter

volume | ? drivetype -eq removable | % driveletter
```

Comment: Now it should be the best answer.

Comment: These answers were the simplest of the lot. Thanks for this!

Answer (score 4):

Beginning with PowerShell v3.0, Microsoft introduce the `Get-Cim*` commands which make this easier than the ugliness of the `Get-WmiObject` ASSOCIATORS query method:

```
Get-CimInstance -Class Win32_DiskDrive -Filter 'InterfaceType = "USB"' -KeyOnly | 
    Get-CimAssociatedInstance -ResultClassName Win32_DiskPartition -KeyOnly |
    Get-CimAssociatedInstance -ResultClassName Win32_LogicalDisk |
    Format-List *
```

Or:

```
Get-CimInstance -Class Win32_DiskDrive -Filter 'InterfaceType = "USB"' -KeyOnly |
    Get-CimAssociatedInstance -Association Win32_DiskDriveToDiskPartition -KeyOnly |
    Get-CimAssociatedInstance -Association Win32_LogicalDiskToPartition |
    Format-List *
```

The above commands are equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

```
$FlashDrives = (get-volume | Where-Object drivetype -eq removable).DriveLetter


foreach($elment in $FlashDrives)
{ 
    if($null -eq $elment)
    {
    
    }
    else
    {
       $FlashDriveLetter = $elment + ":\"
       Write-Host $FlashDriveLetter
    }
}

$HardDiskDrives = (get-volume | Sort-Object -Property DriveLetter | Where-Object drivetype -eq Fixed).DriveLetter

foreach($elment in $HardDiskDrives)
{ 
    if($null -eq $elment)
    {
    
    }
    else
    {
       $HardDiskDriveLetter = $elment + ":\"
       Write-Host $HardDiskDriveLetter
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This gets a single USB drive letter and stores it in the variable $DRIVE. Works in Powershell 7.3.4 where Get-WmiObject doesn't and where the USB drive shows up as Fixed as it does with Get-Volume.

> $DRIVE = (Get-CimInstance -Class Win32_DiskDrive -Filter 'InterfaceType = "USB"' -KeyOnly | Get-CimAssociatedInstance -ResultClassName Win32_DiskPartition -KeyOnly | Get-CimAssociatedInstance -ResultClassName Win32_LogicalDisk).DeviceID