# Powershell: Grab USB Drive letter and run script MDT2013

Tags: powershell, mdt

I'm running a PowerShell script with the following:

> Copy-Item -Path d:\Deploy\Scripts\content\PC-IP -Destination c:\installs -recurse -Force
>   Copy-Item -Path d:\Deploy\Scripts\content\Mobile-license -Destination c:\installs -recurse -Force

This works great, but instead of hard-coding the D drive (USB drive) I was wondering if there is a way to automatically detect the USB drive letter. Something like this: `%usbdrive%`

I have several desktops and laptops that use D, E and F as the USB drive letter.

Thank you,
Justin

Comment: duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10634396/how-do-i-get-the-drive-letter-of-a-usb-drive-in-powershell

Comment: try this `$drives = gwmi win32_volume -filter 'drivetype = 2' | % {$_.driveletter[0]}` or this `$drives = [System.IO.DriveInfo]::GetDrives() | ? drivetype -eq 'Removable' | % {$_.tostring()[0]}` then you can `$drives | % {if (test-path $($_ + ":\deploy\scripts\content\pc-ip")) {$_}}`

Comment: Anthony, Can you show me how I would incorporate my copy-item script into this