# Inno Setup - How to identify a USB drive for source directory

Tags: inno-setup, drive

I would like the Inno Setup compiler to automatically detect USB drive letter and use it a source path for installer files.

But I dont know exactly how to identify the right drive. What is the right `SourceDir=` for that?

The source drive should not be a fix drive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inno Setup cannot do this on its own. But you can invoke a simple PowerShell code from Inno Setup preprocessor.

Based on [Get the drive letter of USB drive in PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10634396/850848#14725897), the following will set `SourceDir` to first removable drive (not necessarily the USB drive, and it won't use USB hard drives). If you really want the first USB drive, try the [answer by @CB.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10634396/850848#10635380)

```
#define GetUsbDrive() \
  Local[0] = AddBackslash(GetEnv("TEMP")) + "usb_drive.txt", \
  Local[1] = \
    "-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Command """ + \
    "$drive = @(Get-WmiObject Win32_Volume -Filter DriveType='2'); " + \
    "if ($drive) { $drive = $drive[0].DriveLetter }; " + \
    "Set-Content -Path '" + Local[0] + "' -NoNewline -Value $drive " + \
    """", \
  Exec("powershell.exe", Local[1], SourcePath, , SW_HIDE), \
  Local[2] = FileOpen(Local[0]), \
  Local[3] = FileRead(Local[2]), \
  FileClose(Local[2]), \
  DeleteFileNow(Local[0]), \
  Local[3]

#define UsbDrive GetUsbDrive()
#if Len(UsbDrive) == 0
#error No USB drive found
#endif

[Setup]
SourceDir={#UsbDrive}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, it worked. You re doing a great job @martin here on stack overflow. You really help me a lot with my projects :)