# Powershell run cmd command line from usb drive

Tags: powershell

I want to run Windows update on multiple computers from a USB stick. 
Connect the USB to the computer, and then start remote powershell to perform the update. 
Is it possible to do this with a powershell command?

From powershell start the command prompt, and then run the command below in cmd. 
I do not know the correct drive letter, this must be my connected USB.
I want to run the powershell command remotly from Pdq deploy.

If I run the update locally on my computer than I use the commandline below in command promt:

```
'D:\Win20H2update\setup.exe /auto upgrade /quiet /Compat IgnoreWarning /ShowOOBE none /DynamicUpdate disable'
```

So I want to run the same command prompt from powershell where the drive letter is my usb drive.

I'm not very handy with powershell. Can you help me with this?

Comment: Try here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10634396/get-the-drive-letter-of-usb-drive-in-powershell

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get the drive letter of USB drive in PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10634396/get-the-drive-letter-of-usb-drive-in-powershell)