# How Can I Correlate Logical Drives and Physical Disks using the WMI and Delphi?

Tags: delphi, wmi, each

I already have a long working on an application that can read information from Micro, some (most) failed more still missing some, I'm working with WMI and Delphi.
The problem I'm facing is that I need to be listed units which belong to each HD, for example: HD1 has drive C:, D: and so on.

thank you

Comment: why is this tagged java?

Comment: Something like this perhaps, [How can i get the drive letter of an usb device?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6656846/576719).

Comment: @Andreas probably something Soft ;-)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To correlate the Logical Drives and Physical Disks you must use the [`Win32_DiskDrive`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394132%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) class and the [`Win32_DiskDriveToDiskPartition`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394134%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), [`Win32_LogicalDiskToPartition`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394175%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)  [ASSOCIATORS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384793%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) classes.

Try this sample.

```
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  SysUtils,
  ActiveX,
  ComObj,
  Variants;


function ListDrives : string;
var
  FSWbemLocator  : OLEVariant;
  objWMIService  : OLEVariant;
  colDiskDrives  : OLEVariant;
  colLogicalDisks: OLEVariant;
  colPartitions  : OLEVariant;
  objdiskDrive   : OLEVariant;
  objPartition   : OLEVariant;
  objLogicalDisk : OLEVariant;
  oEnumDiskDrive : IEnumvariant;
  oEnumPartition : IEnumvariant;
  oEnumLogical   : IEnumvariant;
  iValue         : LongWord;
  DeviceID       : string;
begin;
  Result:='';
  FSWbemLocator   := CreateOleObject('WbemScripting.SWbemLocator');
  objWMIService   := FSWbemLocator.ConnectServer('localhost', 'root\CIMV2', '', '');
  colDiskDrives   := objWMIService.ExecQuery('SELECT DeviceID FROM Win32_DiskDrive');
  oEnumDiskDrive  := IUnknown(colDiskDrives._NewEnum) as IEnumVariant;
  while oEnumDiskDrive.Next(1, objdiskDrive, iValue) = 0 do
   begin
      Writeln(Format('DeviceID %s',[string(objdiskDrive.DeviceID)]));
      //Escape the `\` chars in the DeviceID value because the '\' is a reserved character in WMI.
      DeviceID        := StringReplace(objdiskDrive.DeviceID,'\','\\',[rfReplaceAll]); 
      //link the Win32_DiskDrive class with the Win32_DiskDriveToDiskPartition class
      colPartitions   := objWMIService.ExecQuery(Format('ASSOCIATORS OF {Win32_DiskDrive.DeviceID="%s"} WHERE AssocClass = Win32_DiskDriveToDiskPartition',[DeviceID]));
      oEnumPartition  := IUnknown(colPartitions._NewEnum) as IEnumVariant;
      while oEnumPartition.Next(1, objPartition, iValue) = 0 do
      begin
       if not VarIsNull(objPartition.DeviceID) then
       begin
        Writeln(Format('   Partition %s',[string(objPartition.DeviceID)]));
        //link the Win32_DiskPartition class with theWin32_LogicalDiskToPartition class.
        colLogicalDisks := objWMIService.ExecQuery('ASSOCIATORS OF {Win32_DiskPartition.DeviceID="'+VarToStr(objPartition.DeviceID)+'"} WHERE AssocClass = Win32_LogicalDiskToPartition'); 
        oEnumLogical  := IUnknown(colLogicalDisks._NewEnum) as IEnumVariant;
          while oEnumLogical.Next(1, objLogicalDisk, iValue) = 0 do
          begin
              Writeln(Format('     Logical Disk %s',[string(objLogicalDisk.DeviceID)]));
              objLogicalDisk:=Unassigned;
          end;
       end;
       objPartition:=Unassigned;
      end;
       objdiskDrive:=Unassigned;
   end;
end;

begin
 try
    CoInitialize(nil);
    try
      ListDrives;
    finally
      CoUninitialize;
    end;
 except
    on E:Exception do
        Writeln(E.Classname, ':', E.Message);
  end;
  Readln;
end.
```

This will output something like so

```
DeviceID \\.\PHYSICALDRIVE0
   Partition Disk #0, Partition #0
     Logical Disk F:
DeviceID \\.\PHYSICALDRIVE1
   Partition Disk #1, Partition #0
     Logical Disk C:
```

Comment: RRUZ - is there any way you could post a version that works with Lazarus 1.4.0 and Freepascal? I read your RoadToDelphi entry (https://theroadtodelphi.wordpress.com/2010/12/01/accesing-the-wmi-from-pascal-code-delphi-oxygene-freepascal/#Lazarus) but despite making the changes I could only get PhysicalDisks to list. The logical drive lettering etc would not show because the following returns empty: objWMIService.ExecQuery(Format('ASSOCIATORS OF {Win32_DiskDrive.DeviceID="%s"} WHERE AssocClass = Win32_DiskDriveToDiskPartition',[DeviceID])); I'd REALLY appreciate it

Comment: @RRUZ - success!! You are a genious!! Only one minor issue was while oEnumLogical.Next(1, objLogicalDisk, ivalue) = 0 do  needed changing to while oEnumLogical.Next(1, objLogicalDisk, nil) = 0 do  but thanks to your article I had worked that out earlier already. Seriously, many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Using MagWMi wrapper and its one-liner function (the one-liner is slow - but that is not the place where speed is needed).
I used it to make 2-level disks list.

- HardDrive 1 -> Letter 1, Letter 2
- HardDrive 2 -> Letter 3, Letter 4
- NetServer 1 -> Letter 5, Letter 6
- NetServer 2 -> Letter 7, Letter 8
- Unrecognized -> All other letters

But You have to remember that some disks may be used without any letter.
So that would tell you info about root directories, but not more.
Disk C: may be spawned to several physical disks.
And some physical disks may be used without letter at all.

```
unit WMI_Helper;

interface

function WMINetDiskName(const disk: string { 'C:' - w/o slash } ): string;
function WMIPhysDiskName(const disk: string { 'C:' - w/o slash } ): string;
function WMIGetVolumeName(const disk: string { 'C:' - w/o slash } ): string;

implementation

uses magwmi, SysUtils, StrUtils, Windows, IOUtils;

function WMIGetProp(const query, param, resultProp: string): string;
begin
  if MagWmiGetOneQ(StringReplace(query, '%s', param, []), resultProp, Result) <= 0
  then
    Result := '';
  Result := Trim(Result);
end;

function WMINetDiskName(const disk: string { 'C:' - w/o slash } ): string;
const
  req = 'select ProviderName from Win32_MappedLogicalDisk where DeviceID = "%s"';
  prop = 'ProviderName';
var
  i: integer;
begin
  Result := WMIGetProp(req, disk, prop);

  If not TPath.IsUNCPath(Result) then
    exit('');

  i := PosEx('\', TPath.GetPathRoot(Result), 3);
  if i <= 0 then
    exit('');

  SetLength(Result, i - 1);
end;

function WMIPhysDiskName(const disk: string { 'C:' - w/o slash } ): string;
const
  resultProp = 'DeviceID';
  reqPart = 'ASSOCIATORS OF {Win32_LogicalDisk.DeviceID="%s"} WHERE ResultClass=Win32_DiskPartition';
  reqDisk = 'ASSOCIATORS OF {Win32_DiskPartition.DeviceID="%s"} WHERE ResultClass=Win32_DiskDrive';
begin
  Result := WMIGetProp(reqPart, disk, resultProp);
  if Result > '' then
    Result := WMIGetProp(reqDisk, Result, resultProp);
end;

function WMIGetVolumeName(const disk: string { 'C:' - w/o slash } ): string;
const
  prop = 'VolumeName';
  reqNet = 'select VolumeName from Win32_MappedLogicalDisk where DeviceID = "%s"';
  reqPhy = 'select VolumeName from Win32_LogicalDisk where DeviceID = "%s"';

begin
  Result := WMIGetProp(IfThen(GetDriveType(PChar(disk)) = DRIVE_REMOTE, reqNet,
    reqPhy), disk, prop);
end;

end.
```