# Enumerating partitions drive letter using WMI in vc++

Tags: windows, visual-c++, com, wmi

I want to get the system drive letter of all partitions on the computer, except the active partition, using WMI, this is what I've came up so far( I don't know how to get the drive letter& how to check if they are all HDDs or system drives so I Don't get any CD-ROM here):

```
 std::vector<CString> GetPartitionsVector(bool bCoInit   = false  )
{
    std::vector<CString> partVect;
    HRESULT hres = NULL;
    if(bCoInit)
    {

        hres =  CoInitializeEx(0, COINIT_MULTITHREADED); 
        if (FAILED(hres))
        {
            goto end_routine;
        }

        hres =  CoInitializeSecurity(
            NULL, 
            -1,                          // COM authentication
            NULL,                        // Authentication services
            NULL,                        // Reserved
            RPC_C_AUTHN_LEVEL_DEFAULT,   // Default authentication 
            RPC_C_IMP_LEVEL_IMPERSONATE, // Default Impersonation  
            NULL,                        // Authentication info
            EOAC_NONE,                   // Additional capabilities 
            NULL                         // Reserved
            );


        if (FAILED(hres))
        {
            goto end_routine;
        }
    }


    IWbemLocator *pLoc = NULL;

    hres = CoCreateInstance(
        CLSID_WbemLocator,             
        0, 
        CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, 
        IID_IWbemLocator, (LPVOID *) &pLoc);

    if (FAILED(hres))
    {
        goto end_routine;
    }


    IWbemServices *pSvc = NULL;

    hres = pLoc->ConnectServer(
        _bstr_t(L"ROOT\\CIMV2"), // Object path of WMI namespace
        NULL,                    // User name. NULL = current user
        NULL,                    // User password. NULL = current
        0,                       // Locale. NULL indicates current
        NULL,                    // Security flags.
        0,                       // Authority (e.g. Kerberos)
        0,                       // Context object 
        &pSvc                    // pointer to IWbemServices proxy
        );

    if (FAILED(hres))
    {
        goto end_routine;
    }

    hres = CoSetProxyBlanket(
        pSvc,                        // Indicates the proxy to set
        RPC_C_AUTHN_WINNT,           // RPC_C_AUTHN_xxx
        RPC_C_AUTHZ_NONE,            // RPC_C_AUTHZ_xxx
        NULL,                        // Server principal name 
        RPC_C_AUTHN_LEVEL_CALL,      // RPC_C_AUTHN_LEVEL_xxx 
        RPC_C_IMP_LEVEL_IMPERSONATE, // RPC_C_IMP_LEVEL_xxx
        NULL,                        // client identity
        EOAC_NONE                    // proxy capabilities 
        );

    if (FAILED(hres))
    {
        goto end_routine;
    }

    // Step 6: --------------------------------------------------
    // Use the IWbemServices pointer to make requests of WMI ----

    // For example, get the name of the operating system
    IEnumWbemClassObject* pEnumerator = NULL;
    hres = pSvc->ExecQuery(
        bstr_t("WQL"), 
        bstr_t("SELECT * FROM Win32_DiskPartition"),                // Win32_DiskPartition
        WBEM_FLAG_FORWARD_ONLY | WBEM_FLAG_RETURN_IMMEDIATELY, 
        NULL,
        &pEnumerator);

    if (FAILED(hres))
    {
        pSvc->Release();
        pLoc->Release();

        goto end_routine;
    }

    // Step 7: -------------------------------------------------
    // Get the data from the query in step 6 -------------------

    IWbemClassObject *pclsObj;
    ULONG uReturn = 0;

    while (pEnumerator)
    {
        HRESULT hr = pEnumerator->Next(WBEM_INFINITE, 1, 
            &pclsObj, &uReturn);

        if(0 == uReturn)
        {
            break;
        }

        VARIANT vtProp;

        // Get the value of the Name property
        hr = pclsObj->Get(L"BootPartition", 0, &vtProp, 0, 0);

        if(!vtProp.boolVal)     //if this is not boot partition, get some more
        {
            hr = pclsObj->Get(L"BootPartition", 0, &vtProp, 0, 0);
            if(FAILED(hr))
            {
                //log here
            }
            hr = pclsObj->Get(L"SystemName", 0, &vtProp, 0, 0);
          if(!FAILED(hr))
              partVect.push_back(vtProp.bstrVal);
        }




        VariantClear(&vtProp);
        pclsObj->Release();
    }

    // Cleanup
    // ========

    pSvc->Release();
    pLoc->Release();
    pEnumerator->Release();



end_routine:

    if(bCoInit)
    {
        CoUninitialize();
    }
    return partVect;
}
```

Comment: Do you have to use WMI?  [This link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc542456(VS.85).aspx) does it using the volume management APIs.

Comment: Searching MSDN for 'WMI drive letter' is also useful.

Comment: This looks good, but I've been doing it another way.. not necessarily the one that you suggested and my application crashed at testing because of some dll missing from some systems... using WMI doesn't crash the app, so this is why  I chose this way, I'll also try the way you suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To correlate the partitions list returned by the [`Win32_DiskPartition`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394135%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) WMI class with a Driver letter (a logical disk) you must use follow this sequence.

1. First call  the [`Win32_DiskDrive`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394132%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) class
2. Then query for all the instances of [`Win32_DiskPartition`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394135%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) using the `DeviceID` property and the [`Win32_DiskDriveToDiskPartition`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394134%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) association class.
3. Now call the [`Win32_LogicalDisk`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394173%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) WMI class that represents the partition using the `Win32_DiskPartition.DeviceID` property and the [`Win32_LogicalDiskToPartition`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394175%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) association class.
4. Finally you can get the drive letter from the `Win32_LogicalDisk.DeviceID` property.

Here you have a set of samples of how to use the `ASSOCIATORS OF` WMI sentence.

- [How to join in a WMI Query (WQL)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3206846/how-to-join-in-a-wmi-query-wql)
- [How Can I Correlate Logical Drives and Physical Disks using the WMI and Delphi?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12271269/how-can-i-correlate-logical-drives-and-physical-disks-using-the-wmi-and-delphi)