# How to get the value of StartingOffset properties in class Win32_DiskPartition

Tags: delphi, winapi, wmi

I got a message

> Method 'StartingOffset' not supported by automation object.

Here is a small part of my code:

```
colLogicalDisks := objWMIService.ExecQuery('ASSOCIATORS OF {Win32_DiskPartition.DeviceID="'+VarToStr(objPartition.DeviceID)+'"} WHERE AssocClass = Win32_LogicalDiskToPartition');
oEnumLogical  := IUnknown(colLogicalDisks._NewEnum) as IEnumVariant;
    while oEnumLogical.Next(1, objLogicalDisk, iValue) = 0 do
    begin
        ShowMessage(objLogicalDisk.StartingOffset);
        driveletter := string(objLogicalDisk.DeviceID);

        if driveletter = ExtractFileDrive(GetCurrentDir) then
        begin
            SetLength(result, 6);
            result[0] := string(objdiskDrive.DeviceID);
            result[1] := string(objdiskDrive.Model);
            result[2] := string(objdiskDrive.MediaType);
            result[3] := string(ConvertBytes(objdiskDrive.Size));
            result[4] := string(objLogicalDisk.Description);
            result[5] := string(ConvertBytes(objLogicalDisk.Size));
        end;
        objLogicalDisk:=Unassigned;
    end;
```

Source code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6653205/how-can-i-get-the-drive-letter-of-an-usb-device/6656846#6656846)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code fails because the `objLogicalDisk` variable holds an instance to the [`Win32_LogicalDisk`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394173(VS.85).aspx) WMI class and you need access to the [`Win32_DiskPartition`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394135(v=vs.85).aspx) class. Also your sample code is not complete but it seems which your are using the code  posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6656846/91299). If that is the case you can access to the `StartingOffset` property via the `objPartition` variable (`objPartition.StartingOffset`)